# Ajax JSON data response to dynamic drop down

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have Ajax JSON response data like

```
{"ID":["53","54"],"NAME":["Volkswagen Project ","Nevpro Project"]}
```

Now I want dynamic drop-down with ID as value and NAME as text.
My Ajax code-

```
$.ajax({

url: "//<?echo $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];?>/services/project_data.php",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    //data: {lan : lan},
    success: function(data){

        $.each(data,function(index, element) {
                               var x = document.getElementById("project");
                               var option = document.createElement("option");
                               option.text = element.NAME;
                               option.value = element.ID;
                               x.add(option);
                    });
    }
});
```

By this code drop-down is added but value and text shows undefined.
Please some one help me to sole this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that `data` is an object. The arrays are in the `ID` and `NAME` properties, so you instead need to loop through those, something like this:

```js
var data = {
  "ID": ["53", "54"],
  "NAME": ["Volkswagen Project ", "Nevpro Project"]
}

// in your success handler:
var html = data.ID.map(function(id, i) {
  return `<option value="${id}">${data.NAME[i]}</option>`;
});
$('#x').append(html.join(''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="x"></select>
```

Note that I used a template literal simply to keep the code tidy. You can change that to use string concatenation if you need to support older browsers.

Comment: can you help me generate array like [ {"ID":"53","NAME":"Volkswagen Project"},
  {"ID":"54", "NAME": "Nevpro Project"} ] using php

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a PHP dev. I'd suggest asking a new question about that - but be sure to include your PHP code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Your data format should be like this, for your UI code to work:

```
[ {"ID":"53","NAME":"Volkswagen Project"},
  {"ID":"54", "NAME": "Nevpro Project"} ]
```

i.e. There should be an array containing two objects. Each object with `NAME` and `ID` properties.